# PieChart For RSForm for PlotaLot based on a dropdown field

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, rsform, pivot, plotalot

So I got this Pie Chart to display the Count of Voters vs Position and it's working fine.

```
SELECT Position,
COUNT(1) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT
      MAX(IF(FieldName = 'Position', FieldValue, NULL)) AS `Position`
    FROM syh4g_rsform_submission_values
    WHERE FormId = 1
    GROUP BY SubmissionId
) DerivedTable
GROUP BY Position
```

Now, I have another field called `Part No` which is basically a dropdown field of numbers starting from 1 to 47 in the same form.

I want to create a Pie Chart for `Part No: 5` only showcasing the Count of `Position` against the Name.

How do I go about it?

EDIT:
Here's a sample of my DB Table. Please note that the sample data has `Part No 5`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eeYuhZSefJ2XsV4Jpmn6Hv/0

Comment: Thanks for your question,  Elaine, please take our [tour].  It looks like you have crafted a good question AND in my opinion, you have tagged your question perfectly.  This indicates that you know you are after a [tag:pivot] query.  The "DerivedTable" hints that you may have toiled with some of my guidance found elsewhere on JSE.  These are all great indicators of your effort.  Could you please create a db-fiddle with a sufficient amount of sample data and your desired output?  It's always good to see people with Stack Exchange experience coming to JSE!

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you are asking for another condition inside of your `MAX()` or if you want a `HAVING` clause.  For instance, will `HAVING MAX(IF(FieldName = 'Part No', FieldValue, NULL)) = '5'` work if you write it after `GROUP BY SubmissionId`?  I might be able to perform the same logic a couple of other ways if you can provide a db sandbox for me.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for your kind words. Currently, the piechart shows for all data. However, I want the piechart only for those data where the `Part No` is `5`.

Comment: Did you try my `HAVING` suggestion in my second comment?

Comment: @mickmackusa HOT DAMN!! Looks like it is working when I added that line of code after `GROUP BY SubmissionId`. Could you post as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a HAVING clause that pre-qualifies aggregrate data in your derived table.  The following condition will require that a submission contains a `Part No` value of `5`.

```
HAVING COUNT(FieldName = 'Part No' AND FieldValue = '5')
```

Full SQL: ([DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eeYuhZSefJ2XsV4Jpmn6Hv/1))

```
SELECT Position,
       COUNT(1) AS Count
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(IF(FieldName = 'Position', FieldValue, NULL)) AS `Position`
    FROM syh4g_rsform_submission_values
    WHERE FormId = 1
    GROUP BY SubmissionId
    HAVING COUNT(FieldName = 'Part No' AND FieldValue = '5')
) DerivedTable
GROUP BY Position
```

---

Less elegantly, it could be:

```
HAVING MAX(IF(FieldName = 'Part No', FieldValue, NULL)) = '5'
```

or

```
HAVING MAX(IF(FieldName = 'Part No' AND FieldValue = '5', 'keep', NULL)) = 'keep'
```

or

```
HAVING '5' IN (MAX(IF(FieldName = 'Part No', FieldValue, NULL)))
```

or

```
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('5', GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FieldName = 'Part No', FieldValue, NULL)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This works perfectly.